# Elementary differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for a way to show that on a surface with $K \leq 0$, no closed geodesic bounds a simply connected region. Can someone help me out with it?

Comment: What is $K$ in your problem?

Comment: @Prototank That must be the Gaussian Curvature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) for surfaces with a boundary:

$$\int_M K\;dA+\int_{\partial M}k_g\;ds=2\pi\chi(M)$$

where $k_g$ is the [geodesic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature).

Let $M$ be the region bounded by a closed geodesic $\partial M$. Since $\partial M$ is a geodesic, the second integral is 0. By your assumption, the first integral is non-positive, so the Euler characteristic of $M$ cannot be positive, while the Euler characteristic of a simply connected region is 1.